# WebApi RoleEntryPoint 404

Tags: asp.net, azure, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, azure-web-roles

I have a strange problem for which I can't find a solution.

Currently we have a development Server (running a normal Azure Virtual Machine) and a production Server running a Web Role in Azure Cloud Services.

For the Web Role we need to add the "RoleEntrPoint" class.

But as soon this class is present, the Web Api on a normal VM on development server with IIS 8 returns a "404" for all routes.

This problem is similar to: http://jake.ginnivan.net/web-api-problem-404s-for-everything/
(As a side note, opposed to the blog post I'm not using EntityFramework. We just added the RoleEntryPoint class and copy local for Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime is true)

But I can't find a solution or catch any errors thrown.

Do you have any ideas on this?

Answer (score 0):

It makes sense that if you're not running as an Azure role, then `RoleEntryPoint` would break things. Can you make your development VM also a Web Role? If not, then don't use `RoleEntryPoint` and use ASP.NET lifecycle management methods instead.

From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.serviceruntime.roleentrypoint.aspx):

> Web roles can optionally extend the RoleEntryPoint class, or can use the ASP.NET lifecycle management methods to handle the start and stop sequences.

So, the ASP.NET methods will work for both VM and Web Role. You didn't say what you're trying to do with the `RoleEntryPoint`, so I'm not sure what further guidance to give.

Comment: I can't make the development VM a Web Role.

As noticed today the 404 seems to occur kinda "random". I completly removed the "AzureRoleEntryPoint" now the WebApi will work for some hours or even days.

But out of a sudden it begins to 404 for all routes, I'm logging all handled/unhandled exceptions but can't see a cause for this.